# Windows SDK | Invalid character in 'Wndows Kit' folder path

Tags: windows, sdk

I'm getting an error when installing a more recent version of the Windows Software Development Kit on my computer.

Each time I'm trying to install it (wherever it's, my `B:\` drive or `C:\PROGRA~X`) I get that error (at 33% of the "installation"):

```
An error occurred while installing Windows Performance Toolkit. Log. 

The folder path 'Windows Toolkit' contains an invalid character.
Review the setup log files, or contact your system administrator.
```

So I then decided to login in an other user (and install in it's program folder), and it didn't worked.

I checked the logs and it simply says that there's an invalid character somewhere but there's no more details.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/wb6S8MMU) is the log files given by the installation program to check the reason of the error (pastebin).

(Also note that in the logs you'll be able to see references to `D:\Windows Kits\10\` which is weird as I actually don't have any storage devices associated to `D`, but I had one before).

I also tried to simply uncheck `Windows Performance Toolkit` in the installation settings (it's the 1st one) but it didn't worked as it will simply display the same error with the next Toolkit to be installed (and the error still displays at exactly 33% of installation).

Is there any known solutions to solve that problem ?

There's probably a registry key which contains an invalid character due to some reasons but I don't know which one it could be if it was the case...

I really need to install the Windows SDK and then install the WDK, and I don't really want to reset my OS for that.

If you need more information or details about something concerning my system I'll provide them.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem.
By checking the log, I found that this problem is caused by the string in the registry.
Search in the registry and delete this field.
That's how I solved it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00FkL.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).